# Running NUnit tests with nunit3-console.exe on build machine fails - but they run fine locally

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

When I try to run the tests from command line on the build machine with

```
nunit3-console.exe TestProject.dll
```

I get the following error:

```
No suitable tests found in TestProject.dll
Either assembly contains no tests or proper test driver has not been found.
```

But I can run the tests locally, both from Visual Studio and from the command line with, so I tests are there. But somehow they just won't run on the build machine.

How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: Verify that you are running the same version of nunit3-console and using the same version of the nunit framework in both environments.

Comment: The framework binaries were missing from the bin folder. The source of the problem was actually to do with the checkout from source control.